# FOSRestBundle—create singular route

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am creating a RESTFul application using the FOSRestBundle (2.0) for Symfony3. I have a Controller like so:

```
class GroupsController extends FOSRestController
{
  public function getGroupAction($id) { … }
  public function getGroupAddAction() { … }
}
```

running `bin/console debug:router` gives:

```
…
get_group            GET      ANY      ajax.localhost.dev    /groups/{id}
get_group_add        GET      ANY      ajax.localhost.dev    /group/add
…
```

But getting a single Group is the request for a single Item, so the route should be: `[GET]  /group/{id}`, in my opinion.

Am I wrong with that? Should the correct route, to get a single group be plural?

So if my opinion is right, how can I change this single route manually? I have tried:

```
  /**
   * @NamePrefix("group")
   */
  public function getGroupAction() { … }
```

But that results in an Error telling me, that I can use that annotation only for the Class, not the method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be plural.

If you want to have singular-routes, you can use this in your controller.
You can find it in the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html).

```
/**
 * @RouteResource("User", pluralize=false)
 */
```

Comment: Could you tell me why it should be plural? Isn't it a single item request?

Comment: Its naming conventions. The url says "give me id `XX` from repository `Groups`" - not "give me `Group X`"